# Can anyboby help find me xpath for below ? i tried with //input[@class='new-todo ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'] but its not able to find it

Tags: selenium, cucumber

https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/ this is the website. and I'm trying to locate text box.
I tried with `Xpath` `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='new-todo ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")).sendKeys("Go to GYM");`

Also with `driver.findElement(By.className("new-todo ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")).sendKeys("Blah");`

But its still not able to locate element , can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

`//input` `xpath` is enough
or `//input[contains(@class,'new-todo')]` `xpath`
or `new-todo` by class name
or `.new-todo` `css selector`
Don't forget to set some delay before accessing the element to let the page and the element completely loaded.

Comment: Its not locating ,i guess its in the placeholder..  i even tried with driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='value in placeholder']")).sendKeys("blah");

Comment: Did you add a delay before to let the page load?
Also possibly you need to hover over this element and click it with Actions?

Comment: oh yes,, you are awesome.. adding some wait it worked.. thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I'm happy I could help you. 
Now please accept and upvote my comment

Comment: sorry, i am new here.. how do i do that ?

Comment: On the left to my answer there are 2 arrows: up and down. Use upper arrow to upvote. This means this answer is useful. Below the down arrow is a 'V' - clicking it means you accepted this answer as it resolved your problem. See the tooltips there.
Thanks

Comment: Done that.. thanks again and have a great day

Comment: I'm sorry, but you did not.. Now I understand you can't upvote until you have 15 points reputation, but you can accept and you didn't do that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers